# Problemas com charset="utf-8"

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, utf-8

Tenho um dado com acendo gravado no banco postgres com UTF-8 exemplo: **José**

Quando recupero a pagina vem corretamente, mas quando dou o submit muda para : **JosÃ©**.

meu cabeçalho JSF esta assim:

```
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </f:facet>

    <title><ui:insert name="tituloPagina">teste</ui:insert></title>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="lib" name="styles/custom.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="lib" name="styles/layout.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="lib" name="styles/components.css" />
    <h:outputScript target="body" library="primefaces"
        name="jquery/jquery.js" />
    <h:outputScript target="body" library="lib"
        name="javascripts/app.js" />

</h:head>
```

E na pagina fica assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt4">
    <head id="j_idt4">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/teste/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bootstrap">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/teste/javax.faces.resource/fa/font-awesome.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/teste/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/teste/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/teste/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/teste/javax.faces.resource/components.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/teste/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/teste/javax.faces.resource/styles/custom.css.xhtml?ln=lib">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/teste/javax.faces.resource/styles/layout.css.xhtml?ln=lib">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/teste/javax.faces.resource/styles/components.css.xhtml?ln=lib">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/teste/javax.faces.resource/javascripts/app.js.xhtml?ln=lib"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/teste/javax.faces.resource/javascripts/progressStep.js.xhtml?ln=lib"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/teste/javax.faces.resource/javascripts/raphael.js.xhtml?ln=lib"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.locale='pt_BR';PrimeFaces.settings.projectStage='Development';}</script>

        <title>Teste</title>
   </head>
```

persistence.xml

```
<!-- Padrao -->  
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x/nomeBanco" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="usuario" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="senha" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />


            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="100" />
```

Form

```
<h:form id="frm">

    <p:toolbar>
        <f:facet name="left">
            <p:button id="btMenuInicial" value="Menu Inicial"
                icon="ui-icon-home" outcome="/Index.xhtml" styleClass="ms-botao150"/>

        </f:facet>

    </p:toolbar>


    <h:panelGroup>


        <p:messages id="msgs" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true"
            closable="true" />

        <h3>Endereço</h3>

        <p:panelGrid layout="grid" columns="4"
            columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-4,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-4"
            styleClass="ms-panelgrid-noborder" style="margin-top:20px">

            <p:outputLabel for="cpCep" value="Cep" />
            <p:inputMask mask="99999-999" id="cpCep" required="false"
                value="#{controller_MB.usuario.cep}">
                <p:ajax update="cpEndereco cpCidade cpBairro cpUF cpNumero cpComplemento"
                    listener="#{controller_MB.buscaCep()}" />
            </p:inputMask>

            <p:outputLabel for="cpEndereco" value="Endereco" />
            <p:inputText id="cpEndereco" required="false"
                value="#{controller_MB.usuario.endereco}" disabled="#{controller_MB.camposCepDesabilidados}" styleClass="js-retira-acento"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="cpNumero" value="Numero" />
            <p:inputText id="cpNumero" value="#{controller_MB.usuario.numero}" disabled="#{controller_MB.camposCepDesabilidados}"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="cpComplemento" value="Complemento" />
            <p:inputText id="cpComplemento" required="false"
                value="#{controller_MB.usuario.complemento}" disabled="#{controller_MB.camposCepDesabilidados}" styleClass="js-retira-acento"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="cpCidade" value="Cidade" />
            <p:inputText id="cpCidade" required="false"
                value="#{controller_MB.usuario.cidade}" disabled="#{controller_MB.camposCepDesabilidados}" styleClass="js-retira-acento"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="cpBairro" value="Bairro" />
            <p:inputText id="cpBairro" required="false"
                value="#{controller_MB.usuario.bairro}" disabled="#{controller_MB.camposCepDesabilidados}" styleClass="js-retira-acento"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="cpUF" value="UF" />
            <p:inputText id="cpUF" required="false"
                value="#{controller_MB.usuario.uf}" disabled="#{controller_MB.camposCepDesabilidados}"/>

        </p:panelGrid>


    <p:button id="btConsulta" value="Cancela" outcome="/Index.xhtml"
        styleClass="ms-botao" />

</h:form>
```

Comment: Marcelo posta como fez a conexão do banco (remova o host, login e senha antes de postar aqui). Pois acho que esse problema se resolve na conexão, também posta a parte do FORM. Esse submit é por ajax ou form normal?

Comment: Coloquei o Persistence.xml

Comment: Marcelo, se puder colocar o Form também ajudaria a ter certeza. Obrigado.